# how can i get value for each slider; javascript only showing one

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm having a hard time trying to make this work and would like some help if someone knows a solution that would be greatly appreciated. !'m still learning java-script and finally learn the on load function but now I'm having a problem trying to get both values show up. if i change anything i get the second slider to work but the first slider stops working.

HTML Code:

```
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p id="value-box">Value: <span id="demo" style="color:#ae81ff;"></span><name id="Seconds"> Seconds</id></p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="1" class="slider" id="W-range">
    <p id="value-box">Value: <span  Name="W-range" id="demo2" style="color:#ae81ff;"></span><name id="Seconds"> Seconds</id></p>
```

Javascript code:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
  }

window.onload = ()=>{
    var slider = document.getElementById("W-range");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    
    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you set the `slider` variable to the the `myRange` slider, but then you redefine `slider` and point it to the `W-range` slider. You should have two separate variables. Also, you don't need `window.onload` at all if you just place your `script` just prior to the closing `body` tag.

Also, there is no `name` HTML element and you've then got that element with a closing `id` tag, which also doesn't exist. Those should just be `span` elements. And, you cannot have two elements with the same `id`, which you are doing with `id="Seconds"`. In reality, you should try to steer away from using `id`'s in the first place because they make your code more brittle and harder to scale. Those elements don't need unique names at all here.

Additionally, since both sliders do the same thing, you only need to write the callback code once. See the comments inline below:

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p id="value-box">Value: 
   <span style="color:#ae81ff;"></span>
   <span> Seconds</span>
</p>

<input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="1" class="slider" id="W-range">
<p id="value-box">Value: 
  <span style="color:#ae81ff;"></span>
  <span> Seconds</span>
</p>

<script>
  // If you place a `script` element just before the closing body tag
  // there is no need for window.onload because by the time the parser
  // reaches this point, all the HTML will have been loaded into memory
  
  // Don't use event properties, use addEventListener()
  document.getElementById("myRange").addEventListener("input", report);
  document.getElementById("W-range").addEventListener("input", report);  
  
  // Both sliders essentially need to do the same thing, but their values
  // need to go in different places. `this` will represent the slider
  // that got the input and then we can get the paragraph sibling that
  // comes after it and query its contents for the span that should display
  // the value.
  function report(event){
   this.nextElementSibling.querySelector("span").textContent = this.value;  
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that help me get it and yes the id was for css both of them instead of individually css coding. im still novice so learning how to make it better and proper

Comment: @RandyCarrero You're welcome. If you want to style several elements the same way, give them all the common `class`, but `id`'s must be unique. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Comment: thank you again. i change them to span class and remove the id's. i also have chosen the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There was just one closing `"}"` after slider.oninput = function() { ... } too much.
You should take a look at your tags in HTML there:`<name id="Seconds"> Seconds</id></p>`
The tag name doesn't exist and the tag id which you are closing (but don't open) as well not

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

window.onload = ()=>{
  var slider = document.getElementById("W-range");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p id="value-box">Value: <span id="demo" style="color:#ae81ff;"></span><name id="Seconds"> Seconds</id></p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="1" class="slider" id="W-range">
<p id="value-box">Value: <span  Name="W-range" id="demo2" style="color:#ae81ff;"></span><name id="Seconds"> Seconds</id></p>
```